# Trying to use Node Request to authenticate

Tags: node.js, authentication, node-request

I'm trying to use the Node module [Request](https://www.npmjs.org/package/request) to authenticate on a website, and after following [instructions](https://www.npmjs.org/package/request#http-authentication) I still can't seem to figure it out...

Using Coffeescript I've done the following:

```
Request {
    url: "https://#{encodeURIComponent(config.email)}:#{encodeURIComponent(config.password)}@#{config.loginURL}"
}, (error, response, body) ->
    if error
        console.log error
    else
        console.log body
```

The `config` values are, respectively, an email, password, and the URL. The URL is `app.shopify.com/services/partners/auth/login`. Also, because the username is an email address, I thought it be best to `encodeURIComponent` the login values.

When I run this I don't get an error, but the output of the `body` is just the markup of the login page.

I've also tried doing it like this:

```
Request.get config.loginURL, {
    auth: {
        username: config.email
        password: config.password
        sendImmediately: false
    }
}, (error, response, body) ->
    if error
        console.log error
    else
        console.log body
```

In this case, because the credentials aren't part of the URL, I haven't `encodeURIComponent`'d them. Also, the login URL has `https://` prepended to it.

Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

Comment: What happened with the second case (is `error` set? what is `response.statusCode`?)? Did you try with `sendImmediately: true`? Did you check `config.email` and `config.password` to make sure they are valid (at least not empty)?

Comment: @mscdex setting `sendImmediately` to `true` didn't seem to do anything (though I'm not sure what "Digest authentication" is), I can confirm that the config values are set and Strings, and the response codes from both cases are 200. So I _think_ everything is set correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the page is not using basic/digest authentication and is instead using form-based authentication, you need to POST form values instead:

```
request(config.loginURL, {
  method: 'POST',
  form: {
    // these key names come from the `name` field in the login form's HTML
    login: config.email,
    password: config.password
  }
}, function(err, res, body) {
  // ...
});
```